# ElementTree find returns None?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using `ElementTree` with Python to parse an XML file to find the contents of the tag `contentType`.

Here's the Python line:

```
extensionType = ET.parse("src/" + str(filename)).find('contentType')
```

And here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <cacheControl>Private</cacheControl>
    <contentType>image/jpeg</contentType>
</StaticResource>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are just parsing the xml file so far. this is how you can get your element using xpath (note how you have to use the given xml namespace `xmlns`)

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

xmlns = {'soap': '{http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}'}
ct_element = root.find('.//{soap}contentType'.format(**xmlns))
print(ct_element.text)
```